# Importing to sql from csv in changing order of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import, multiple-columns

I'm using SQL 2012. I would like to create a stored procedure in SQL that would delete a table and then create one based on an import from a csv file. Simple enough so far.

The issue is that the columns in my CSV file will probably be changing in order, due to some issues that are out of my control. I plan on identifying the columns with a name that will be linked to another name in a table as well (again, out of my control).

For example (in CSV):

```
Name1           Name2      Name3
1                3           2
22               4           3
3                13          12
41               8           1
22               6           4
```

In metadata table:

```
Names         ID      
Name1         ID1           
Name2         ID2           
Name3         ID3
```

And the table I want to create via import:

```
ID1           ID2      ID3
1             3         2
22            4         3
3             13        12
41            8         1
22            6         4
```

The issue being that the names of the columns won't always be in the same order, any given day I could be given a CSV that would look like this:

```
Name3         Name2        Name1
2               3           1
3               4           22
12              13          3
1               8           41
4               6           22
```

How would you go about naming via something like an inner-join, the columns in the table?

Comment: Will the column names in the file always be the same (even if they are in a different order)?

Comment: Yes, the names will always be the same!

Answer (score 0):

This makes a few assumptions: always 3 columns, all data is type int, destination table is static, etc.  If your needs are more complex, you might start looking at a dedicated ETL tool.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Import (
  @filename varchar(max)
) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
  DECLARE @columns_i nvarchar(max)
  DECLARE @columns_o nvarchar(max)

  CREATE TABLE #header ([1] sysname, [2] sysname, [3] sysname)
  SET @sql = N'BULK INSERT #header FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@filename) + ' WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0D0A'',FIRSTROW = 1, LASTROW = 1);'
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql

  SELECT @columns_i = ISNULL(@columns_i+',','') + QUOTENAME([column]) + ' int' FROM #header UNPIVOT([column] FOR [colnum] IN ([1],[2],[3])) p ORDER BY [colnum]
  SELECT @columns_o = ISNULL(@columns_o+',','') + QUOTENAME([Names] + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME([ID]) FROM MyMetadata ORDER BY [Names]

  SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE #data ('+@columns_i+');'
  SET @sql = @sql + N'BULK INSERT #data FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@filename) + ' WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0D0A'',FIRSTROW = 2);'
  SET @sql = @sql + N'SELECT '+@columns_o+' FROM #data'

  INSERT MyDestination
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The table structs used:

```
create table mapTable(
    inCsv varchar(max),
    inSql varchar(max)
);

create table csvImported(
    Name1 int,
    Name2 int,
    Name3 int
);
```

Here, im supposing you already have a table with your csv data imported.
So, im populating the csvImported table with some stuff, just to  test. The map table, the same.

> Populating the mapTable table;

```
insert into mapTable values ('Name1', 'ID');
insert into mapTable values ('Name2', 'ID2');
insert into mapTable values ('Name3', 'ID3');
```

> Populating the csvImported table;

```
insert into csvImported values (11, 122, 333);
insert into csvImported values (110, 1422, 37833);
insert into csvImported values (101, 1252, 33213);
```

So, here is the procedure definition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE_FROM_CSV(
    @CsvTableName varchar(max),
    @WantedTableName varchar(max)

) AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @vColumnList            varchar(max) = '',
        @vColumnName            varchar(max) = '',
        @vColumnNameRenamed     varchar(max) = '',
        @vColumns               TinyInt = 0,
        @vTableNameInSql        varchar(max) = @WantedTableName,
        @vTableNameInCsv        varchar(max) = @CsvTableName,
        @vDoCreateTable         varchar(max) = '';

        if ((select OBJECT_ID('ShadowMapTable')) > 0 ) 
        begin 
            drop table ShadowMapTable;
        end;    

        select * into ShadowMapTable from mapTable;

        select      t1.name
        from        sys.columns t1 
        join        sys.tables t2 on (t1.object_id = t2.object_id)
        join        ShadowMapTable t3 on (t1.name = t3.inCsv)
        where       t2.name = @vTableNameInCsv;

        set @vColumns = @@rowcount;

        WHILE (@vColumns > 0)
        begin
            select      @vColumnName = t1.name, @vColumnNameRenamed = t1.name + ' as ' + t3.inSql
            from        sys.columns t1 
            join        sys.tables t2 on (t1.object_id = t2.object_id)
            join        ShadowMapTable t3 on (t1.name = t3.inCsv)
            where       t2.name = @vTableNameInCsv

            -- Define the ColumnListRenamed -> used in the into clause.
            if (@vColumnList = '')
            begin 
                set @vColumnList = @vColumnNameRenamed
            end else
            begin
                set @vColumnList = @vColumnNameRenamed + ',' + @vColumnList;
            end;

            delete from ShadowMapTable
            where       inCsv = @vColumnName

            select      t1.name, t3.inCsv, t3.inSql
            from        sys.columns t1 
            join        sys.tables t2 on (t1.object_id = t2.object_id)
            join        ShadowMapTable t3 on (t1.name = t3.inCsv )
            where       t2.name = @vTableNameInCsv

            set @vColumns = @@rowcount;
        end;

        set @vDoCreateTable = '
                                if((select object_id('''+@vTableNameInSql+''')) > 0) 
                                begin 
                                    drop table '+@vTableNameInSql+'; 
                                end; 

                                select ' + @vColumnList + ' into ' + @vTableNameInSql + ' from ' + @vTableNameInCsv + ';';
        --print @vDoCreateTable;
        exec    (@vDoCreateTable);
        exec    ('select * from ' + @vTableNameInSql);
        print   ('Table created: ' + @vTableNameInSql);
```

Finally, how you should call the Proc.

```
exec CREATE_TABLE_FROM_CSV 'csvImported', 'wantedTableName';
```

I really hope it help.

Kind regards,
Victor.